# Opencart Errors

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am having issues with my Opencart shop (version 2.0). I have not made any changes in a few days and my hosting company don't work weekends... and something always seems to go wrong on weekends.

When I try to log in to my admin panel I get this error:

> Warning: session_start():
>   open(/tmp/sess_6944b43ff0351f3609154764b353ba7c, O_RDWR) failed:
>   Permission denied (13) in
>   /home/thespace/public_html/system/library/session.php on line
>   23Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter -
>   headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/thespace/public_html/admin/index.php:165) in
>   /home/thespace/public_html/system/library/session.php on line 23

The front end of the website works with the exception of the checkout... It gives me this error when trying to access it:

> Warning: session_start():
>   open(/tmp/sess_6944b43ff0351f3609154764b353ba7c, O_RDWR) failed:
>   Permission denied (13) in
>   /home/thespace/public_html/system/library/session.php on line
>   23Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter -
>   headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/thespace/public_html/index.php:207) in
>   /home/thespace/public_html/system/library/session.php on line
>   23Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/thespace/public_html/index.php:207) in
>   /home/thespace/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php
>   on line 28Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already
>   sent by (output started at /home/thespace/public_html/index.php:207)
>   in
>   /home/thespace/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php
>   on line 29
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   /home/thespace/public_html/index.php on line 205

I have tried googling the issue but can't seem to find a resolve. I did notice that there was no public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php file in my vqcache and I've tried restoring an old backup of the site but that hasn't worked either!

Really need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all files of `vqmod/vqcache` and delete the file `vqmod/mods.cache`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check that is there vqmod in the site if it is then :

1) delete the mods.cache and checked.cache file from vqmod folder
2) delete all cache files from vqmod/vqcache

second check there is any Extension installed through OCMod if any then Go to Admin and clear and refresh the modification.

I think these will help because it helps me once.

Answer (score 0):

```
It seems the plugin/extension you have installed using VQMOD/OCMOD is not working properly somehow.

Here are some ways to show the error message:

1. Set your “Output Compression Level” to 0 in the System > Settings > Server tab.
2. Then open php.ini and add code below:
           I. display_errors = 1;
           II. error_reporting = E_ALL;
           III. log errors = 1;
3. If your server not read the php.ini, we will use an alternative method. Open index.php and add code below at the top (line 2):
           I. ini_set('display_errors', 1);
           II. ini_set('log_errors', 1);
           II. error_reporting(E_ALL);
4. Once you have fixed the problem, remove the above code.

   If It's just warning then You should do inverse process.
   You have to disable display error using Admin Panel of Opencart Application.
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. delete vqcache
2. delete mods.cache
3. delete checked.cache
4. clear modification
   Amy is right. This just helped my friend.